# Can I create an xml file at a specified location using XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

My windows application is creating a xml file and adding data to it using `XElement`. Is there any way i can create this file in D:/ directly rather than the project bin folder(default). I want a web service to access this xml file to perform some function. So in that case i want it in some generic folder whenever this application is run on any system.

the code used to create and update the xml

```
x = new XElement("Data");
x.Add(new XElement("DataClass",
      new XElement("pathI", txt_input.Text),
      new XElement("pathO", txt_Output.Text),
      new XElement("prefix", txt_prefix.Text),
      new XElement("frequency", Convert.ToInt32(txt_freq.Text))));
x.Save("Data.xml");
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me, the file gets created in the bin\debug folder. YOu might want to try `x.Save("Path to file" + "data.xml");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried (at the end where you specify the file name):

```
x.Save(@"D:\DirectoryName\Data.xml");
```